# On click, I want to add the value of an a-tag to an inputfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

Html:

```
<input type="text" title="Ort, gata eller kommun" value="something">
<a href="#">Teramo, Italy</a>
```

I want it so that when the a-tag is clicked, the input-tag value is set to "Teramo, Italy"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $("input").val($(this).text());
});
```

But you would be better off assigning them classes or IDs, e.g.:

```
<input class="location" type="text" title="Ort, gata eller kommun" value="something">
<a href="#" class="location">Teramo, Italy</a>

$("a.location").click(function() {
    $("input.location").val($(this).text());
});
```

Or targeting the input relative to the clicked anchor via traversal, e.g.:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $(this).prev("input").val($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: it should be `$(this).text()`, as there is no attribute `text`

Comment: @Gaby - I know, and I fixed it again :( <sigh>

Comment: Yay! I love getting something out of my screw-ups :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.link').click(function() {
  $('input').val($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**javascript**

```
$('a.toinput').click(function(){
  $('#display').val( $(this).text() );
})
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="display" title="Ort, gata eller kommun" value="something">
<a href="#" class="toinput">Teramo, Italy</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="input1" type="text" title="Ort, gata eller kommun" value="something">
<a id="a1" href="#">Teramo, Italy</a>

$("#a1").click(function() {
    $("#input1").val(this.value);
});
```

Just an FYI, in case you're going to have more than one anchor tag and input element... You probably want to give them IDs so you can refer to them directly.